# Need help writing validation Rule on custom object!

Tags: custom-object, picklist, validation-rule

I need help writing a validation rule to make specific fields on a custom object required based on met criteria...can one of you awesome people help?

What is the Expected End Result:

a) When `Platform` = `EQC`, make ‘`EQC Login`’ mandatory

- `Platform__c` = Picklist
- `EQC_Login__c` = Text

b) When `Platform` = `EQC` AND `Status` = ‘`Connected`’ , make ‘`Go Date`’ mandatory.

- `Platform__c` = Picklist
- `Status__c` = Picklist
- `Go_Date__c` = Date

Comment: Are you looking for a validation rule that has an Error Condition Formula such as: `ISPICKVAL(Platform__c, 'EQC')  && ISBLANK(EQC_Login__c)`. When the formula is true display a message telling the user that EQC Login is mandatory?

Comment: Yes, that is the hope anyways. Wasn't sure if I could keep it all in one rule or if two rules needed to be written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you would need two validation rules

**EQC Login validation Rule:**

**Error Condition Formula:**

```
ISPICKVAL(Platform__c, 'EQC') && ISBLANK(EQC_Login__c)
```

**Error message:**

> EQC Login is a mandatory field

---

**Go Date validation Rule:**

**Error Condition Formula:**

```
ISPICKVAL(Platform__c, 'EQC') && ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Connected') && ISBLANK(Go_Date__c)
```

**Error message:**

> Go Date is a mandatory field